# Getting "undefined method `myobjects_path'" when trying to render my Rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I’m using Rails 4.2.3.  I’m having trouble getting my form to render.  I’m getting the error "undefined method `myobjects_path' for #<#:0x007f8362cc01e0>" on the line "<%= form_for @myobject do |f| %>" when I visit my “http://localhost:3000/users” page.  The code below is from my “app/views/users/_add.html.erb” file …

```
<%= form_for @myobject do |f| %>
  <% if @myobject.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@myobject.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this hack from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
```

here is the method in my “app/controllers/users_controller.rb” from which this page is accessed …

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @myobject = Myobject.new
  end
end
```

What do I need to do to get my form to render?

Comment: do you have in your config/routes.rb `resources :useres`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This occurs when the object in the form (@myobject in this case) is a new_record and has no id.  The form will call the path method, usually intending to go to "/myobjects" to be used as the form source.  If it was not a new record, it would go to the details path (/myobjects/:id).

In this case there is no method `myobjects_path` because you probably haven't created the method anywhere yet.  It's easy to create in routes.  Just make sure you have a `resources :myobjects` and it doesn't exclude the create action

Answer (score 0):

In controller add method

```
def new
   @myobject = Myobject.new
end

def create

end
```